# How would I generate a generic list of undetermined length

Tags: c#

I am trying to generate a List of a pizza ordering histor project in c#. However for return for a method, I am unsure on the possible max length of the list to be return, unsure on what direction to go now.

just trying to set the method return right now, so no code inside of the method, just unsure what to put between the <> brackets, because there might be 1 pizza string inside of the list or there might be 99 pizza strings.

```
// for the return values they would be (multiple strings of different pizza names (problem), datestamp, cost, pizza store location) 

public List<List<>(problem area), int, decimal, string> OrderHistory()
{
  // empty code
}
```

Comment: Lists already have a dynamic size and can expand, you don't need to put the size in the declaration.

Answer (score 2):

if the list is just an any size you can have it return `List<string>` or `List<Model>` it doesnt need a size set i.e.

```
public List<MyModel> DoAThing()
{
    List<MyModel> myList = new List<MyModel>();

    MyModel addThing = new MyModel();
    addThing.Name = "Tomato";
    addThing.Colour = "Red";

    myList.Add(addThing);

    return myList;
}
```

(of course my example only has one item, but add the every living hell out of it, you dont need to specify size)

On top, if you want a list of lists, create a new model and have a list as a property of that model, you can list lists of lists with lists if you really want, just architect that sucker.